# abort an http request Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: ajax, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile, titanium-alloy

Am using 3.1.3.GA Titanium SDK, Alloys and 2.3.3 Android Emulator. I am trying to post an Ajax using **Ti.Network.createHTTPClient()** and at some point I need to abort it, Now I am trying this code and its not getting work or ajax request not getting abort. My code,

**index.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window backgroundColor="white">
        <Label onClick="sendAjax">Send</Label>
        <Label onClick="cancelAjax">Cancel</Label>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**index.js**

```
function sendAjax(){
var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
        xhr.onerror = function(e){
            var error = e.error;
            alert(error);               
        };
        xhr.open('GET', url);
        xhr.send(params);
        xhr.onload= function(e){
            if (this.readyState == 4) {
                  alert('success');
            }
            else if (cancelSend) {
                  xhr.abort();
            }
        };
        xhr.ondatastream = function(e){
            if(ajaxCancel){
                xhr.abort();
            }   
        };
}

function cancelAjax(){
    ajaxCancel = true;  
}
```

Is it possible to abort an ajax request, else have to change code at anywhere. Anyone got success in aborting ajax request using appcelerator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

until now there is no solution for: abort ajax request using HttpClient object.

I have been trying code to find out a solution but I gave up. Is not a big problem to detect when you have aborted a request and stop sending following requests in code, but the HttpClient object won't stop performing the requests that are already being sent.

**If you can wait** until next releases:

Someone has filled in an issue regarding this problem [TIMOB-15612](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-15612) and is already solved, maybe solves yours too.

**If you can't**:

After some googling I saw [this post](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154693/httpclient---how-to-stop-an-upload-in-progress---abort) where they point out that the solution comes by 
using [TCP sockets](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.Socket.TCP), and they suggest looking some code [here](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/144392/android-httpclientabort-does-not-stop-file-upload)

**If what you want is** to detect when you have aborted a request and stop sending following requests:

According to [HTTPClient sdk 3.x documentation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154693/httpclient---how-to-stop-an-upload-in-progress---abort) the onload property:

Must be set before calling open.

And the same happens with ondatastream and onreadystatechange properties.

Your index.js code should be reorganized and I'd suggest you something like this:

```
Ti.Network.HTTPClient.UNSENT = 0;
Ti.Network.HTTPClient.OPENED = 1;
Ti.Network.HTTPClient.HEADERS_RECEIVED = 2;
Ti.Network.HTTPClient.LOADING = 3;
Ti.Network.HTTPClient.DONE = 4;

var ajaxCancel = false;
var xhr = createHTTPClient();
var url = "";    //MUST BE SET BEFORE USE
var params = ""; //MUST BE SET BEFORE USE
function createHTTPClient(){
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onerror = function(e){
        Ti.API.info("-----------------------");
        var error = e.error;
        Ti.API.info("onerror:" + error);               
    };
    xhr.onreadystatechange= function(e){
        Ti.API.info("-----------------------");
        Ti.API.info("[onreadystatechange]readyState:" + xhr.readyState);
    };
    xhr.onload= function(e){
        Ti.API.info("-----------------------");
        Ti.API.info("[onload]");
        if (!ajaxCancel && this.readyState === Ti.Network.HTTPClient.DONE) {
            Ti.API.info("[onload]success:");// + JSON.stringify(e));
        }else{
            Ti.API.info("[onload]readyState:" + xhr.readyState);
            if(ajaxCancel){
                Ti.API.info("[onload]abortCall:");// + JSON.stringify(e));
            }else{
                Ti.API.info("[onload]:");// + JSON.stringify(e));
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.ondatastream = function(e){
        Ti.API.info("-----------------------");
        if(ajaxCancel){
            Ti.API.info("[ondatastream]abortCall:");// + JSON.stringify(e));
        }else{
            Ti.API.info("[ondatastream]:");// + JSON.stringify(e));
        } 
    };
    return xhr;
}
function sendAjax(){
    if(ajaxCancel)
        return;
    Ti.API.info("----------CALL---------");
    //xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    Ti.API.info("Ti.Network.HTTPClient.UNSENT:" + Ti.Network.HTTPClient.UNSENT);
    Ti.API.info("Ti.Network.HTTPClient.OPENED:" + Ti.Network.HTTPClient.OPENED);
    Ti.API.info("Ti.Network.HTTPClient.HEADERS_RECEIVED:" + Ti.Network.HTTPClient.HEADERS_RECEIVED);
    Ti.API.info("Ti.Network.HTTPClient.LOADING:" + Ti.Network.HTTPClient.LOADING);
    Ti.API.info("Ti.Network.HTTPClient.DONE:" + Ti.Network.HTTPClient.DONE);
    Ti.API.info("[sendAjax]before request");
    xhr.send(params); //params not needed for a GET operation
    Ti.API.info("[sendAjax]request send");
}

function cancelAjax(){
    if(!xhr || ajaxCancel)
        return;
    Ti.API.info("-----------------------");
    Ti.API.info("[cancelAjax]abort petition");
    xhr.abort();
    Ti.API.info("[cancelAjax]abort call executed");
    ajaxCancel = true;
    if(xhr.readyState === Ti.Network.HTTPClient.UNSENT ||
       xhr.readyState === Ti.Network.HTTPClient.DONE){
        //maybe it wasn't already sent or the cycle is completed
        Ti.API.info("[cancelAjax]request not send or already done: " + xhr.readyState);
    }else{
        Ti.API.info("[cancelAjax]xhr.readyState:" + xhr.readyState);
    }

}
function allowAjaxCalls(){
    ajaxCancel = false;
}
```

In your index.xml add another label/button to control if you want to allow sending request after having canceled them:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window backgroundColor="white">
        <Button onClick="sendAjax">Send</Button>
        <Button onClick="cancelAjax">Cancel</Button>
        <Button onClick="allowAjaxCalls">AllowSend</Button>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```